# SQL Server - SELECT WHERE three columns on three separate tables are equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Trying to make a query that pulls from one table on the condition that the unique ID on the items for that table are found in related ID columns on other tables.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
inner join Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID
inner join Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.Table1ID
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID and Table1.ID = Table3.Table1ID
```

For example, let's say you're a doctor, and Table1 is a list of patient encounters. Table2 is a list of patient diagnoses, and Table3 is a list of patient treatments. The items on Table1 and Table2 will always have a Table1ID, but items on Table1 might not always have a corresponding item on Table2 or Table3.

An aside, is there any way to do a sort of triple equals? Such as...

```
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID = Table3.Table1ID
```

Comment: You just have to put the condition thrice. For eg . T1.id = t2.id and t1.id = t3.id and t2.id = t1.id.  Hope that is clear.

Comment: Your join does this.  Equality is transitive.  The `where` clause is unnecessary.

Comment: Focusing on this part of your question "_items on Table1 might not always have a corresponding item on Table2 or Table3_" if you are saying there may be no matching data in Table3, then the answer is (probably) to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific problem, you just don't need the `where` condition - the join condition already satisfies it:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Table1ID
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.Table1ID
```

As a general question, a neat trick is to check if multiple value are equal is to check if the smallest is equal to the largest:

```
LEAST(a, b, c, d, e) = GREATEST(a, b, c, d, e)
```